# Quadratic optimization in Qiskit: Error when QuadraticProgram with quadratic constraint converted to QUBO

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, optimization

I prepared a quadratic optimization task with binary and integer variables and linear and quadratic constraints. I fed it into `QuadraticProgram` in Qiskit. After that, I tried to convert the program to binary optimization task with constraints in form of equality only. I used `InequalityToEquality` and `IntegerToBinary` converters to do this. However, an error was returned. After some trial and error, I realized that the problem is caused by the quadratic constraint, so I removed it and everything is fine.

**My questions are:**

1. Is the problem really in the quadratic constraint? Or in other words, are such constraints forbidden when I want to use converters?
2. If so, is there any other way how to convert `QuadraticProgram` to QUBO in Qiskit?
   *(note that `QuadraticProgramToQubo` also does not work since `IntegerToBinary` is part of it)*

Here is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
from qiskit.optimization import QuadraticProgram
from qiskit.optimization.converters import InequalityToEquality, IntegerToBinary, QuadraticProgramToQubo

#create empty optimization task (model)
mod = QuadraticProgram('Quadratic optimization problem') #string in brackets - user defined name of the task

#adding variables
mod.binary_var(name = 'x') #bin
mod.integer_var(name = 'y', lowerbound = 0, upperbound = 5) 
mod.integer_var(name = 'z', lowerbound = 0, upperbound = 5) 
#setting objective function
mod.minimize(constant = 3, linear = [1,0,1], quadratic = [[1, 0, 2],[0,1,0],[2,0,1]])
#adding constraints
mod.linear_constraint(linear = {'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z':1}, sense = '==', rhs = 1, name = 'L1')
mod.linear_constraint(linear = {'x': -1, 'y': -1, 'z':2}, sense = '>=', rhs = 0, name = 'L2')
mod.linear_constraint(linear = {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z':30}, sense = '<=', rhs = 100, name = 'L3')

#PROBLEMATIC QUADRATIC CONSTAINT
mod.quadratic_constraint(linear = {'x':1, 'y':1}, quadratic = {('x','y'):1, ('x','z'):-1}, sense = '<=', rhs = 2, name = 'Q1')

modConverted = InequalityToEquality().convert(mod)
modConverted = IntegerToBinary().convert(modConverted)
print(modConverted.export_as_lp_string())
```

And here is the returned error:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-f345029f5fa8> in <module>
     20 
     21 modConverted = InequalityToEquality().convert(mod)
---> 22 modConverted = IntegerToBinary().convert(modConverted)
     23 print(modConverted.export_as_lp_string())

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/optimization/converters/integer_to_binary.py in convert(self, problem)
     96                         )
     97 
---> 98             self._substitute_int_var()
     99 
    100         else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/optimization/converters/integer_to_binary.py in _substitute_int_var(self)
    199             )
    200             quadratic, q_linear, q_constant = self._convert_quadratic_coefficients_dict(
--> 201                 constraint.quadratic.to_dict()
    202             )
    203 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/optimization/converters/integer_to_binary.py in _convert_quadratic_coefficients_dict(self, coefficients)
    137         quadratic = {}
    138         for (name_i, name_j), v in coefficients.items():
--> 139             x = self._src.get_variable(name_i)
    140             y = self._src.get_variable(name_j)
    141 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/optimization/problems/quadratic_program.py in get_variable(self, i)
    243             return self.variables[i]
    244         else:
--> 245             return self.variables[self._variables_index[i]]
    246 
    247     def get_num_vars(self, vartype: Optional[VarType] = None) -> int:

KeyError: 0
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your report.
I investigated the details and fixed the bug with [this pull request](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/pull/1256).

Comment: Thank you for help. May I ask you to inform me when the bug is fixed?

Comment: It's merged to master.

Comment: This is very much needed by me, hopefully I shall get it soon. It is still happening for me though.